# Ruby regex: replace non-word chars that are not space chars

Tags: ruby, regex

How do I replace all non-word chars (\W) that are also not space characters (\s)?

This is the desired functionality:

`"the (quick)! brown \n fox".gsub(regex, "#")`

=>

`"the #quick## brown \n fox"`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
"the (quick)! brown \n fox".gsub(/[^\w\s]/, "#")
```

By making the regex replace anything that is NOT a word character OR a space character.

Answer (score 11):

I think you need a regex like this one:

```
/[^\w\s]/
```

When you add a circumflex `^` to the start of a character set, it negates the expression so that anything except characters in the set are matched.

Comment: still have things like `underscore`, that's non word too